# Create a PDF and send as attachment with flask-mail

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail, python-pdfkit

I am trying to create a PDF from an HTML page using pdf-kit, then send that pdf as an attachment in an email.

Here is my code to create the pdf, this seems to be working:

```
                html = render_template("office_report.html",role=role, name=name,owner=off,reps=reps,all_weekly=all_weekly,we=we,totals=totals,cog=cog,all_weekly_rpt=True,off_rpt=off_rpt,v=v,adonors=adonors,ae=ae,ov=ov,pay_total=pay_total)
                options = {"enable-local-file-access": None}
                try:

                    pdf=pdfkit.from_string(html,False,options=options)
                    files =  pdf
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pdf='ERROR'
```

Then I try to send the email, but do not understand how to attach the PDF to the Email.

```
try:

                    msg = Message('Owner Report ', sender = ("Brand Drivers",BD), recipients = ['jesswholt@gmail.com',BD,comp])
                    msg.body = "Weekly Report" + str(we)
                    
                    with app.open_resource(files) as fp:
                        msg.attach("Owner Report", "invoice/pdf", fp.read())
                    mail.mail.send(msg)
                    print('sent')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

Here is the HTML that is converted into the PDF

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<title>Childhelp</title>

<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


</head>
<body>

            <div class="header">
                <h4 class="title">Office Report <br>{{owner.owner_name}}<br>{{owner.office_ID}}</h4>
                <p>WeekEnding: {{we.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')}}</p>
            </div>


                  <table  id="office_weekly" class="table table-hover table-striped">

                      <thead>
                        <th>Ambassador</th>
                        <th>Transactions</th>
                        <th>Total Payments</th>
                        <th>Items Sold</th>
                        <th>Hotlines</th>
                        <th>Bonuses</th>
                      <!--  <th>Total</th>-->
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {% for r in reps %}
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <strong>{{r.rep_name}}</strong><br>
                              {{r.rep_ID}}
                            </td>
                            {% for w in all_weekly if w.rep == r.rep_ID %}
                            <td>{{w.transactions}}</td>

                            <td>
                              Cash: ${{w.cash/100}}<br>
                              Check: ${{w.check/100}}<br>
                              Card: ${{w.card/100}}<br>
                              <strong>Total: ${{w.total/100}}</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              Sold: {{w.tot_itm}}<br>
                              Refunded: {{w.refunds}}<br>
                              Amount Refunded: {{"$%.2f" % (w.amount_refunded/100)}}<br>
                              Refund Dates {{w.dates_refunded}}

                            </td>
                            <td>
                              Active: {{w.subs}}<br>
                              Cancels: {{w.can}}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{"$%.2f" % (w.bonus | float)}}</td>

                            {% else %}
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Report Incomplete</td>
                          </tr>
                          {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <tr>
                          <td><hr></td>
                          <td><hr></td>
                          <td><hr></td>
                          <td><hr></td>
                          <td><hr></td>
                          <td><hr></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>

                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th></th>
                      </tr>
                      <td>Office Sub Total:</td>
                      <td>{{totals.transactions}}

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Cash: {{totals.cash}}<br>
                        Check: {{totals.check}}<br>
                        Card: {{totals.card}}<br>
                        Total: {{totals.sales}}<br>
                        Overrides: {{"$%.2f" % (ov | float)}}

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Items: {{totals.t_items}}<br>
                        COG: {{"$%.2f" % (cog)}} per piece<br>
                        Total COG: {{"$%.2f" % (totals.total_cog)}}

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Total Hotlines for Office:<br>
                        Active: {{totals.hotlines}}<br>
                        Canceled: {{totals.cancels}}<br>

                        Total Pay Hotlines: {{"$%.2f" % (totals.hotlines | float * 15)}}

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Total Bonuses Paid: {{totals.bonus}}<br>

                        Items Refunded: {{totals.items_refunded}}<br>

                        Amount Refunded: {{totals.amount_refunded / 100}}

                      </td>
                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th> Line Items</th>
                        </tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      <td><strong>Balance Carry: {{off_rpt.balance_carry}}</strong></td>

                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      <td><strong>Deposit: {{off_rpt.deposit}}</strong></td>

                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      <td><strong>Events: {{totals.events}}</strong></td>

                      </tbody>
                      <tbody>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      <td><strong>Line Items:</strong></td>

                      <td>
                        Name: {{v.li1_n}}<br>
                        Amount: ${{v.li1_p}}<br>
                        Name: {{v.li2_n}}<br>
                        Amount: ${{v.li2_p}}<br>
                        Name: {{v.li3_n}}<br>
                        Amount: ${{v.li3_p}}<br>
                        Name: {{v.li4_n}}<br>
                        Amount: ${{v.li4_p}}
                      </td>
                      </tbody>

                      <tbody>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      {% if pay_total %}
                        <td><strong>Owner Payout:</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>{{"$%.2f" % (pay_total | float)}}</strong></td>
                      {% else %}
                        <td><strong>Card Sales:</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>{{totals.card}}</strong></td>
                      {% endif %}
                      </tbody>

                      <tbody>
                        <td>
                          <h3>Hotline Signups</h3>
                        </td>
                      </tbody>
                      <thead>
                        <th>Donor Name</th>
                        <th>Ambassador</th>

                        <th>Signup Date</th>
                        <th>Canceled</th>

                      <!--  <th>Total</th>-->
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {% for d in adonors %}
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{d.donor_name}}</td>
                          {% for x in reps if x.rep_ID == d.rep_ID %}
                          <td>{{x.rep_name}}<br>{{x.rep_ID}}</td>
                          {% endfor %}

                          <td>{{d.monthly_start_date}}</td>
                          {% if d.donor_status == False %}
                            <td>{{d.monthly_stop_date}}</td>
                          {% else %}
                            <td style="color:green">Active</td>
                          {% endif %}
                        </tr>

                        {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>

                  </table>
                  <div class="col-md-18">

                  </div>




    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
with app.open_resource(files) as fp:
    msg.attach("Owner Report", "invoice/pdf", fp.read())
```

just do this:

```
msg.attach("Owner Report", "invoice/pdf", pdf)
```

`pdf` (or `files`) contains your file as a bytes type object. So you don't need to use `open_resource` and read a file, because you already have the data you need.

Comment: when I try this way it sends a blank attachment?

Comment: Can list the value of `pdf` and `html`?

Comment: yes, if I return HTML it works perfect, and if I call print(pdf) it prints in terminal

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you could add the output of these variables to the question so the blank attachment problem is reproducible. Just the output of `html` is probably sufficient.

Comment: I have added the HTML to the original question

Comment: The html looks to be fine. I passed some dummy values to `render_template` and I was able to get a nice looking pdf as an attachment using the code in my answer combined with your template. I think the problem is that your first try catch is failing for some reason which sets `pdf` to `'ERROR'`. If I set `pdf` to `'ERROR'` and send the mail gmail can't preview the file. So I would inspect what's happening there.

Comment: I have eliminated the catch just to see if that was the issue. Still a blank pdf in the email. The PDF function is working, because I can return the PDF as a page and it is perfect, however when I attach to the email, I just get an unopenable attachment